# SELECT based on table of declared columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to run multiple `SELECT` commands which select the same sets of columns but from different databases and was hoping to only have to list the columns once as a variable then call that for the SELECTs.

How it is currently done, but with much fewer columns & SELECTs:

```
SELECT Column1
      ,Column2
      ,Column3
FROM [db1]

--Processes

SELECT Column1
      ,Column2
      ,Column3
FROM [db2]

--Processes

SELECT Column1
      ,Column2
      ,Column3
FROM [db3]

--Processes
```

Idea of what I'm hoping to get working:

```
DECLARE @ListofColumns VARCHAR;
SET @ListofColumns = 'Column1,Column2,Column3';

SELECT @ListofColumns
FROM [db1]

--Processes

SELECT @ListofColumns
FROM [db2]

--Processes

SELECT @ListofColumns
FROM [db3]

--Processes
```

Comment: You would have to use dynamic SQL to do this, and that would complicate the code.

Comment: Dynamic SQL (EXEC/sp_executeSQL) is the only way to do this, object identifiers cannot be stored in variables.

Comment: This may be a case where you could use the (undocumented) `sp_MSforeachdb` and `sp_MSforeachtable` stored procedures, with appropriate filters to just target the databases and tables that are important to you, provided the structure of each query is identical. But in such a case, I'd first question why data of the same "type" is being stored in multiple places - has part of the *data* instead become *metadata* by accident (here, by becoming the database name)?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use dynamic sql here something like this.....

```
DECLARE @ListofColumns VARCHAR(1000)  --<-- Define length here 
       ,@SQL NVarchar(MAX);

SET @ListofColumns = 'Column1,Column2,Column3';

SET @SQL = N'SELECT ' + @ListofColumns +  N' FROM [db1]'

exec sp_executesql @SQL
```